# Symfony 2.x Form Field Name

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

When I render a form, form Filed Name is given as an array. For example: `search[item]`, `search[keyword]` etc. where search is name of the form.

I'm not great on working with forms but I think, the name should be rendered as simply, `name="item"` or `name="keyword"`.

I've looked at all the documentation, customizing form rendering topic etc. but I can't find any way to change the default behaviour of Symfony form to render form filed name from 'search[item]' to 'item'. 
This way, when I ask for the POST data, I can ask simply `$this->getRequest()->request->get('item')`, as I have to deal with lots of individual parameters.

Help would be great i) To figure out how to achieve what I want. ii) to let me know, why the name is rendered this way. is this the good practice?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than accessing parameters from the `Request` object, you can bind the `Request` object to the form.

For example, in your controller method that you post your form to:

```
namespace Acme\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use Acme\Form\MyFormClass;

class MyFormController extends Controller
{
    receiveFormAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = new MyFormClass();

        // you can specify that a route only accepts a post 
        // request in the routing definition
        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            // this populates the form object with the data 
            // from the form submission
            $form->bind($request);

            if ( ! $form->isValid()) {
                throw new \Exception('Invalid form');
            }

            // an array of the data the format you require
            $data = $form->getData();

            $data['item'];
            $data['keyword'];
            // etc.
        }
    }
}
```

The above is the way you should be handling forms in Symfony 2, and is how you can leverage the power that the forms component gives you, with validation etc.

Comment: Very good advice, checking validity and binding are Symfony standard practice.

Comment: Agreed that, this is good advice. Thanks Pete. I'm not sure if this is exactly what I will be able to do to achieve what I want, just because the way every other part of the application is working. I will give it a go though.

Comment: Strangely enough having a look at the [symfony form documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class), it says that `$request->get('item')` should work, although it advises that the `getData()` method I showed above is preferable.

Comment: Looking at my question, I should have slightly changed it. You are right that, it works. My problem there is, to combine pre-set bunch of data-set (which I call parameters) from different source (where one of them is request) and pass them to service after filtering unique according to priority order.
I can do $searach = $this->getRequest->request->all(); and use $search['search']. But it's a bit ugly. Hope it make sense to you that it's something un-common I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow exactly, but post some more example code if you need any more help

Comment: I will try little bit more to make some changes to architecture to be able to follow your suggestion above and get back to it but it's already have been a great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony supports multiple forms on a page.  They might be instances of the same form or have similar field names. Having the fields for each form all together in an array makes this easy to do.

Comment: Thanks Peter. It completely makes sense and kind of answer my question(more a curiosity) ii. I still think, there should be the way to change the default behaviour for flexibility, which I'm missing.

Comment: Symfony forms have always been prone to contention.  I believe that Francois (the other founder) left after a disagreement about forms back around version 1.2. The support seems to change every second release, you might be in luck next time :)